# How to create a keyboard shortcut for SublimeREPL

Tags: macos, sublimetext, sublimerepl

I am new to Sublime Text 2 on Mac OS.
I installed the package SublimeREPL.

Is it possible to create a keyboard shortcut to run the file with SublimeREPL?

More precisely, here is a screenshot. I want to avoid going through this menu and run quickly with a keyboard shortcut.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set keyboard shortcuts for any menu item that you can select, in any app.

1. Go to **System Preferences** → **Keyboard** → **Shortcuts** → **App Shortcuts**

   [image]
2. Click the **+** to add a new shortcut.
3. Set the **Application** to `Sublime Text.app`, the **Menu Title** to the exact name of the menu option, and choose a **Keyboard Shortcut**.

   [image]
4. Click **Add**.

Answer (score 74):

You can set a keyboard shortcut for the *command in your screenshot* using Sublime key-bindings.

1. Open Sublime.
2. Go to **Preferences > Key Bindings - User**
3. Add these lines to the opened file between brackets:

   ```
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+b"], "command": "run_existing_window_command", "args":
    {
        "id": "repl_python_run",
        "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
    }}
   ```
4. Save it.

It's done! You can type any key-combinations instead of `"ctrl+alt+b"`, but make sure it's not reserved by Sublime itself (check in **Preferences > Key Bindings - Default**)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Very helpful answer. Solved it for me on Linux and saved from a giant pain!

Comment: Works fine on Mac OS X as well. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Works on Sublime 3, Windows 10 as well.

Answer (score 3):

I found that I lost the keybinding to the installed sublimeREPL, so I had to find how to get it back, since it is a time saving indispensable for me. I used it also on a pc that had not sublime Repl and worked for both. This worked for me in 2019, version 3.2

in preferences / keybinding (after you installed package control and sublimeREPL). I made this [video](https://youtu.be/Zbf2_VRbgQA) too.

```
[

{"keys": ["ctrl+b"], "command": "repl_open",
 "caption": "Python - RUN current file",
 "id": "repl_python_run",
 "mnemonic": "d",
 "args": {
    "type": "subprocess",
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "cmd": ["C:/Users/giova/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/python.exe", "-u", "-i", "$file_basename"],
    "cwd": "$file_path",
    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
    "external_id": "python",
    "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
        }}
]
```

p.s.: change the location of the python.exe as it is stored in your pc.

You can also do this:

```
[

{"keys": ["ctrl+b"], "command": "repl_open",
 "caption": "Python - RUN current file",
 "id": "repl_python_run",
 "mnemonic": "s",
 "args": {
    "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},
    "cmd": ["py", "-u", "-i", "$file_basename",],
    "type": "subprocess",
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "cwd": "$file_path",
    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
    "external_id": "python",
    "view_id": "*REPL* [python]",
        }}
]
```

To use different version of python, you can type py -2.7 for example, if you have them installed.
You can also use 'python' in the cmd list.
To see where the location of python is, you can import sys and look at sys.path from python itself. You can also add "-m", "-pdb" to do the debugging, using another key combination maybe.

This works again in 3.2

```
[
{ "keys": ["ctrl+b"], "command": "run_existing_window_command", "args":
{
    "id": "repl_python_run",
    "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
}}
]
```

Comment: Thanks for this . Working on W10 and Sublime3.2 .

Answer (score 1):

[Go to Preferences -> Key Bindings, and write this in the window "Sublime-keymap --User"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTpEH.png)

```
[
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+b"],
    "command": "repl_open",
    "args": {
                "cmd": ["python", "-u", "-i", "$file_basename"],
                "cwd": "$file_path",
                "encoding": "utf8",
                "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},
                "external_id": "python",
                "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                "type": "subprocess"
            }
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

i have an addition to Romina's answer, 
i used her code, but it opens with Python default version, in my case (Linux Mint) it was Python 2.7,
so if you have that trouble just change her code with this:

```
[
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+b"],
    "command": "repl_open",
    "args": {
                "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "-i",     "$file_basename"],
                "cwd": "$file_path",
                "encoding": "utf8",
                "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"},
                "external_id": "python3",
                "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                "type": "subprocess"
            }
}]
```

And it works with Python 3 (if you have it installed of course)

Answer (score 0):

tq, add debug

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+b"], "command": "run_existing_window_command", "args":
        {
        "id": "repl_python_pdb",
        "file": "config/Python/Main.sublime-menu"
        }
},
```